# Identify trailing space character at the end of string using Reg Exp

Tags: regex, whitespace

I need to report data which has spaces at the end of string ( trailing or leading spaces only). I tried using below keywords but its not working.

```
[ \f\t\v]+$
```

`\b \b` ( this works only if space is between two words but space between one word and one number fails) Can someone please help with this requirement.

My current Reg Exp: `^[a-zA-Z&-',.\s]`

but `\s` matches all spaces ( both between the words and at the end of string) so its not giving expected results.

Comment: Use only one `\b` at the EOL (before `$`)

Comment: How about `\h+$` or `\s+$`

Comment: @zer00ne can you please tell me exact req exp where should i use one \b  ? My current Reg Exp: ^[a-zA-Z&-',.\s]
same que for Toto, where should i add \h+$ in this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```js
var string1 = ' abra kadabra hokus pokus';
var string2 = 'abra kadabra hokus pokus2 ';
var string3 = ' 1abra kadabra hokus pokus ';
var string4 = 'abra kadabra hokus pokus';

var regex=/(^\s|\s$)/;

console.log(regex.test(string1));
console.log(regex.test(string2));
console.log(regex.test(string3));
console.log(regex.test(string4));
```

Comment: I am not looking only for trailing space. I need to make sure my strong contains only ^[a-zA-Z&-',.] . Along with this I also need to report if any trailing spaces. Can you please let me know where to add your code in this reg exp?

Comment: You asked for "I need to report data which has spaces at the end of string  ...",test reports "true or false", if you need something else then ask the full question what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` is what you need. The replacement is `''` and the `g`lobal flag which enables `.replace()` to continue to search after the first match.

```js
var str1 = ` 1abra kadabra hokus pokus`;
var str2 = `abra kadabra hokus pokus2 `;
var str3 = ` 3abra kadabra hokus pokus3 `;
var str4 = `abra kadabra4 hokus pokus`;
var rgx = /^\s+|\s+$/g;

console.log(str1.replace(rgx, ''));
console.log(str2.replace(rgx, ''));
console.log(str3.replace(rgx, ''));
console.log(str4.replace(rgx, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z&-',.]+ )*[a-zA-Z&-',.]+$
```

The pattern is saying that it must be zero or more *word-followed-by-space*, followed by a *word*.

The `^` will *anchor* the pattern to match the start of the value, and the `$` anchors at the end of the value. The combination of those two means the pattern will only match if the entire value matches. Without the anchors, the pattern would match anything which contains the pattern. Your RegEx in the question only has the start anchor, so it will match a value starting with the pattern you have given.

Assumption: I have used your RegEx without the space as the definition of a *word*; but you might want the dot comma (etc) to be part of the word separator rather than part of the word. If so, then wrap the space with square brackets, and move those characters in there.

P.S. remember that the hyphen within square brackets is used as a range indicator, so `[&-']` means the range of characters from ampersand to apostrophe. If you are just trying to have hyphen as a character, make it the first character inside the brackets to avoid that ambiguity.

Also note that your question talks about numbers and your pattern doesn't cover that, so you may need to add `0-9` to both of the *word* definitions.